# what is the meaning of "units of kilobytes * seconds-of-execution"?

Tags: aix

I use getrusage api on aix.
I don't understand ru_idrss field.

ru_idrss
An integral value of the amount of unshared memory in the data segment of a process (expressed in units of kilobytes * seconds-of-execution).

Answer (score -1):

As you know getrusage is an api to get usage of resources. The description says, in other words, the unit of ru_idrss is calculated like `kilobytes multiply seconds-of-execution`.

Thank you!